# confusion with result of Ushort

Tags: c#

consider the following code :

```
ushort a = 60000;
a = (ushort)(a * a / a);
Console.WriteLine("A = " + a);
```

//This prints 53954. Why??

and

```
ushort a = 40000;
a = (ushort)(a * a / a);
Console.WriteLine("a = " + a.ToString());
```

//This prints 40000. how??

any help appreciable ...

Comment: This is C# and not Java. Same as in a question you asked a few minutes ago. Is it homework?

Comment: sorry juergen it was my mistake its c# code ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because 60000^2 is 3600000000 but the biggest number an int can hold is 2,147,483,647, so it starts over from -2,147,483,648.

A ushort can hold 65,535 and then starts over from 0:

For instance, this prints 0:

```
ushort myShort = 65535;
myShort++;
Console.WriteLine(myShort); //0
```

It's easier to see this if you break it into steps:

```
var B = A * A;
```

That actually exceeds the capacity of an int32, so it starts from -2,147,483,648 thus `b` equals -694967296
Then when you split B/A you get: -11582 which, when cast into a ushort becomes 53954.

```
ushort A = 60000;
var B = A * A; //-694967296
var C = B / A; //-11582
ushort D = (ushort)(C); //53954
```

The reason that 40000 works is that it does not exceed the capacity of an int32.

```
ushort A = 40000;
var B = A * A; //1600000000
var C = B / A; //40000
ushort D = (ushort)(C); //40000
```

`uint` can hold 60000^2 though, so this works:

```
ushort A = 60000;
var B = (uint)A * A; //3600000000
var C = B / A; //60000
ushort D = (ushort)(C); //60000
```

The reason that casting C to ushort yeilds 53954 is because the bytes of C is:

```
96
234
0
0
```

And the bytes of D is:

```
96
234
```

So they hold the same backing bytes, that's why you get 53954 and -11582

Answer (score 3):

Because it's equivalent to

`A * A = -694967296` because the result ends up as an int, and overflow on the short gives a bit pattern that yields this negative result.  Ultimately `60000 * 60000` can't be stored in a `ushort`. Add a watch in debug mode and you'll see this.

Then you have

`-694967296 / 60000` - which yields `-11582` as an int, but when cast to a ushort yields 53954 - again because of the underlying bit pattern.

Really, this code would need to be in a `checked` block because it's for this very reason that overflow errors cause massive issues.

Comment: Best explanation according to me. Rest of the answers kind of only state the obvious, the interest part is how 53954 is achieved and why.

Comment: @maka - thanks; at least, it was until I was out-edited by Oskar lol :)

Comment: Haha yeah I noticed that too:)

Answer (score 1):

First good Question! Now let me tell you one thing If you try 40000 it will work fine.

the reason is that **(40000 ^  2)** that is the highest limit of ushort so it will convert into integer so it will not truncate !

If you use **60000** it will ! Due to limit restriction !

Try it with **40000** !

Hope you get my answer

Comment: 40000^2 is not the limit of ushort